# How to cross compile lttng-modules for arm64?

Tags: linux, compilation, cross-compiling, gnu-make, lttng

I have been trying to do it using the arm64 toolchain but got an error `error: unrecognized command line option '-mgeneral-regs-only'`. On googling thi suggested I use the aarch64 toolchain for msm, which I did. But now I'm getting this error `error: conflicting types for 'trace_sched_migrate_task'
 void trace_##_name(_proto);
/local/mnt2/workspace/kernel/include/linux/tracepoint.h:168:21: note: previous definition of 'trace_sched_migrate_task' was here
  static inline void trace_##name(proto)`

Although the same compiles on another Linux system with the same function definitions.

Answer (score 0):

msm kernel has an extra "load" parameter added for trace_sched_migrate_task(), see [commit adding load in msm-4.4](https://github.com/upstream-caf-kernels/msm-4.4/commit/8e7389b5c2130b62ceafb7cc9d6a2ae00bfbcf5a)

LTTng does not provide support for it currently as you can see in [the definition in LTTng sources](https://github.com/lttng/lttng-modules/blob/master/instrumentation/events/lttng-module/sched.h#L298). Adding the support would require just detecting the msm kernel and adding the parameter.